# Restrict an Excel column to only be able to copy values with text format

Tags: excel, vba, validation, format

I have a "NUMERICAL" column which is the source column where I am going to copy the data and then I have a "TEXT" column which is the destination column where I am going to paste the data that I have copied.

As you can see in the image, the numbers column is in numeric format and the text column is in text format.

[image]
[image]

Also, to column A ("TEXT") I have put a data validation (the one that appears in the image), as I understand it, this validation is going to give me an error if I try to put something that is not text.

[image]

Now I want to paste the number that is in the numbers column, the cell is in numerical format and I am going to copy with ctrl + c and paste with ctrl + v in the empty underlined cell, which, as seen in the image, already has text format and it also has the validation

[image]

[image]

When I do this, the format of the cell where I want to paste the value changes to numeric and it ignores the validation that I have done and everything. What could I do to force the values entered in this cell to always have a text format origin?

If someone can help me with this I would be eternally grateful, I hope I have explained myself well.

Comment: When using `Ctrl + C` followed by `Ctrl + V`, **you copy format, too**! The validation you try is also useless. What I think you can do ist to configure the worksheet `Change` event **to convert** everything pasted in the respective column as text...

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much for your help, and how could I do what you tell me?

Comment: I will post an answer in a minute...

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next code in the respective sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.column = 1 And Target.Columns.count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.TextToColumns Target, , , , , , , , , , Array(1, 2)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It works even if you copy more such cells, but only if the copied range has **a single column**. I think, if necessary, the code can be adapted to also accept more columns to be copied, but format as text only the range first column. Not much more complicated...

If something not clear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I have put this VBA code in the excel sheet and I have copied the value of column 4 in column 1 that is preset as text and when I do ctrl + c and ctrl + v it keeps copying the value in numerical format

Comment: What parameters do I have to change to apply this code to column number 8 instead of 1?

Comment: @Abel Pérez I am not sure I've got you... Do you mean that copying numbers from any place **in A:A column**, "keeps copying the value in numerical format"? I dare to not believe that, if copied the code in the respective sheet code module... No matter if it is "preset as text" or not. I would answer the second question after clarifying the first comment.

Comment: I was copying the code in a sheet that was not, it already works for me, now I just need to know how to apply the code to column 8. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Abel Pérez The code has the next part 'telling" which column to process: `If Target.column = 1 And Target.Columns.count = 1 Then`. In order to process the eighth column instead of the first one, you should only change `Target.column = 1` with `Target.column = 8`. The code can be adjusted to do it in both columns, too. But you must state it... You did not say anything about the need to copy more columns, but formatting as text only the first one. I am used to clearly ask something and also to receive an answer, an opinion to the proposed aspects...